# Send plain text via sockets in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

I'm writing a replacement for an old library we use at the office to communicate with a rather clumsy and old custom-made C++ framework that takes requests via sockets in order to communicate with a bunch of other systems.  The problem is that it will only take plain text messages containing a string which must be formatted in a very specific way.

The problem I'm facing is that I haven't found so far a way of sending plain text through the socket. The Send method of the socket will only take byte arrays, and while the listening point receives the data, it gets there completely scrambled, and there's no way I can mess with that in order to convert the byte array back to plain text. I need to be able to send plain text, not byte arrays.

This is the Connect and the Send method I have so far:

```
    Public Sub Connect(Optional ByVal pHostName As String = "", Optional ByVal pPort As Integer = 0)
    If pHostName.Trim <> "" Then mHostName = pHostName
    If pPort > 0 Then mPort = pPort

    Try
        Dim ipep As IPEndPoint

        If IsIPAddress(mHostName) Then
            ipep = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(mHostName), mPort)
        Else
            ipep = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Dns.GetHostEntry(mHostName).AddressList(0).ToString), mPort)
        End If
        mSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        mSocket.Connect(CType(ipep, EndPoint))
        mState = eState.Connected
        RaiseEvent Connected()
        mDataTimer.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Close()
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub SendData(ByVal pBytes() As Byte)
    mSocket.Send(pBytes)
End Sub

Public Sub SendString(ByVal pString As String)
    Dim bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pString)
    mSocket.Send(bytes)
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What service/script or application is on the other side? Explain more, so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you really sure that you should use unicode? Since it's an old C++ application I bet that the encoding should be plain old `Encoding.ASCII` or a charset like `iso-8559-1`.

There is no "send as plain text" when using sockets. It's always byte streams that are being used. The old application is simply interpreting the received bytes as strings using a specific encoding.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! It was way too easy, how come I couldn't come up with that?